# В результате инкрементирования индекса прямо в строке присваивания, элементы массива сдвигаются вправо

Tags: php, инкремент

Хочу заполнить с помощью цикла `while` массив числами от 1 до 10. В результате инкрементирования `$i` прямо в инструкции присваивания - элементы "сдвинуты" на единицу, то есть

```
arr[0] = NULL, arr[1] = 1, arr[2] = 2 и тд...
```

хотя индекс указан ДО увеличения (и отладка это подтверждает).

```
$i = 0;
$arr= [];
while ($i<10) {
    $arr[$i] = (++$i);
}

for ($it = 0; $it < 10; $it++) {
    echo $arr[$it] . "<br>";
}
```

Результат:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Examples\chapter4\operations\index.php on line 92
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5
>   6
>   7
>   8
>   9

Особенности интерпретатора PHP? Java, например, нормально относится к инкременту в одной строке.

Comment: Не надо в вопрос впихивать все метки, которые вы знаете. Достаточно одной-двух по теме)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В строке

```
$arr[$i] = (++$i);
```

в правой части, вы сначала увеличиваете индекс на единицу а потом делаете по этому индексу присвоение. Поэтому у вас все сдвигается на единицу в право

```
$i = 0;
$arr= [];
while ($i<10) {
    $arr[$i] = $i + 1;
    $i++;
}

for ($it = 0; $it < 10; $it++) {
    echo $arr[$it] . "<br>";
}
```